# Attempt to again present UIViewController after it has been dismissed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, segue

So I have view controller A, B, and C.
From A, I present VC B modally over the current context.
There is a button in VC B from where I present VC C (using segue)

Now on dismissing Viewcontroller C, I am trying to dismiss VC B and from VC A, run some function which again presents VC B based on some logic.
But in this case, I get this error "`Attempt to present UIViewController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy`"

I have tried to dismiss with a completion handler, dispatchQueue(after:)
but those doesn't work.

On the contrary, I have a `UIButton` attached in VC A, which runs the same logic for presenting VC B and it is running correctly and not showing any error.

What am I missing in this scenario?

Comment: place your code too

Answer (score 1):

I hope these two solutions help you.

I had the same problem these two solutions helped me with this issue.

**First:**
Post notification in VC C viewDidDisappear or in your button click method and add its receiver on VC B which you want to close it after closing VC C.

**Second:**
You can create a protocol While clicking the button call your protocol method and pass your data to your viewController.